# Automatically call HTMLBeaufity when exiting Insert mode in Vim

Tags: vim, js-beautify

I'd like to automatically format html and js code when I exit insert mode. Currently I have ctrl f mapped to format the current file in my vimrc:

```
map <c-f> :call JSBeautify()<cr>
```

Is there a way I can trigger this command each time I exit insert mode?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps try here (also): http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Will do thanks @Alex

Comment: FYI my code sample should say JsBeautify()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put this

```
augroup AuJsBeautify
   au!
   au  InsertLeave * call JsBeautify()
augroup END
```

in your .vimrc.

*To know more about autocommands, read [`:h 40.3`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_40.txt.html#40.3) and [`:h autocommand`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html).*

---

Or if you prefer mapping, you can just map it on your <kbd>Esc</kbd>

```
inoremap <Esc> <Esc>:call JsBeautify()<cr>
```

Comment: Works great! Small typo (on my part)-  needs to be JsBeautify(). Thankyou!